# UiPickerView not work until its rows are scrolled ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView . It is working fine . But it doesn't select any row until rows are scrolled .

**Here is my code.**

```
 selectProArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",
                                                         @"DEF",
                                                         @"IJK",
                                                         nil];

 selectPROPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
 selectPROPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:209.0/255.0 
                                                    green:213.0/255.0 
                                                    blue:219.0/255.0 
                                                    alpha:1];

 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
         selectedPickerRow=[selectProArray objectAtIndex:row];
         NSLog(@"SelectedRow=%@",selectedPickerRow);
         rowID = row;
         [selectField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: is that 'selectField' is a textField? and ur problem is, textField not updating the value from pickerView at first time, but textField will update on scrolling picker View. right???

Comment: @ShebinKoshy - YEs , It is a textfield. And you are right ? It is not updating first time.

Answer (score 2):

to make select a row in pickerView

```
picker= [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

to update the values in textField, set delegate for ur textField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   textField.text = [self.yourArrayName objectAtIndex:[self.yourPickerName selectedRowInComponent:0]];//component index may differ for u
}
```

Comment: @Ammy first do this, if you already doing anything in this delegate, u have to paste this code after all.. If you need, u can also check condition to affect only for first time by `if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])`

Comment: @Ammy can u paste screen shot of your problem